# How can I change the speed of a stepper motor?

Tags: arduino-uno, stepper

I am new to Arduino and am trying to implement different rotational speeds for a stepper motor. I am using a Nema 17 bipolar stepper motor, a Big Easy Driver, and an Arduino Uno.

I've been trying to modify a tutorial code such that it will run at variable speeds:

```
//Declare pin functions on Arduino
#define stp 2
#define dir 3
#define MS1 4
#define MS2 5
#define MS3 6
#define EN  7

//Declare variables for functions
char user_input;
int x;
int y;
int state;

#include <AccelStepper.h>
#include <Stepper.h>
Stepper stepper1 (1,stp,dir);

void setup() {

  pinMode(stp, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dir, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MS1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MS2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MS3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(EN, OUTPUT);
  resetBEDPins(); //Set step, direction, microstep and enable pins to default states
  Serial.begin(9600); //Open Serial connection for debugging
  stepper1.setSpeed(1);
  Serial.println("Begin motor control");
  Serial.println();
  //Print function list for user selection
  Serial.println("Enter number for control option:");
  Serial.println("1. Turn at default microstep mode.");
  Serial.println("2. Reverse direction at default microstep mode.");
  Serial.println();

}

//Main loop
void loop() {
  while(Serial.available()){
      user_input = Serial.read(); //Read user input and trigger appropriate 
function
      digitalWrite(EN, LOW); //Pull enable pin low to set FETs active and allow motor control
      if (user_input =='1')
      {
         StepForwardDefault();
      }
      else if(user_input =='2')
      {
        ReverseStepDefault();
      }
      else
      {
        Serial.println("Invalid option entered.");
      }
      resetBEDPins();
  }
}

//Reset Big Easy Driver pins to default states
void resetBEDPins()
{
  digitalWrite(stp, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dir, LOW);
  digitalWrite(MS1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(MS2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(MS3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(EN, HIGH);
}

//Default microstep mode function
void StepForwardDefault()
{
  Serial.println("Moving forward at default step mode.");
  digitalWrite(dir, LOW); //Pull direction pin low to move "forward"
  for(x= 1; x<4000; x++)  //Loop the forward stepping enough times for motion to be visible
  {
    digitalWrite(stp,HIGH); //Trigger one step forward
    delay(1);
    digitalWrite(stp,LOW); //Pull step pin low so it can be triggered again
    delay(1);
  }
  Serial.println("Enter new option");
  Serial.println();
}

//Reverse default microstep mode function
void ReverseStepDefault()
{
  Serial.println("Moving in reverse at default step mode.");
  digitalWrite(dir, HIGH); //Pull direction pin high to move in "reverse"
  for(x= 1; x<4000; x++)  //Loop the stepping enough times for motion to be visible
  {
    digitalWrite(stp,HIGH); //Trigger one step
    delay(1);
    digitalWrite(stp,LOW); //Pull step pin low so it can be triggered again
    delay(1);
  }
  Serial.println("Enter new option");
  Serial.println();
}
```

Adjusting the potentiometer on the Big Easy Driver will either stop the motor turning completely or run at a constant speed regardless of further adjustment.

Do you have any suggestions for debugging my code, or are there other functions I should be using in addition to/instead of those I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you understand how a stepper works?  You send it pulses and it steps for each pulse you send it.  The faster you send the pulses the faster it will run.  The slower you send the pulses the slower it will run.  You have lines in your code like this:

```
void StepForwardDefault()
{
  Serial.println("Moving forward at default step mode.");
  digitalWrite(dir, LOW); //Pull direction pin low to move "forward"
  for(x= 1; x<4000; x++)  //Loop the forward stepping enough times for motion to be visible
  {
    digitalWrite(stp,HIGH); //Trigger one step forward
    delay(1);
    digitalWrite(stp,LOW); //Pull step pin low so it can be triggered again
    delay(1);
  }
  Serial.println("Enter new option");
  Serial.println();
}
```

Can you see the part that is sending HIGH and LOW to your step pin?  See the delay that is determining how fast those pulses go out?  Can you imagine how you might change that delay so that the pulses go out faster or slower?  Here's a hint, delay works in milliseconds, but if you want to go faster than this then you'll need to work in microseconds.  Can you find the version of delay that works in microseconds in the Arduino reference?

Comment: Thank you, I found the delayMicroseconds() command which helped significantly!